# Simple JavaScript Slideshow with NO preloading

Tags: javascript, html

I think this is a very simple question, so forgive me if it's been answered elsewhere. I looked but wasn't able to find what I was looking for. I have very little experience with JavaScript.

I have a many simple JavaScript slideshows contained on a single page that advance via a mouse click. See below for the code I'm using, which I've lifted from one of the introductory JS sites. This preloads each image from each slideshow when a user visits the page. I would like the script to NOT preload each image, and instead load the next image only when the user clicks to advance the slideshow. This is to reduce load time, since most users will not encounter most images. Is there an easy way to convert this into something that doesn't preload each image?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var i=0
var imgs=["/a.jpeg","/b.jpeg","/c.jpeg","/d.jpeg","/e.jpeg"]
function slide(){ {i=i+1} {if (i==5) {i=0}} {document.img.src=imgs[i]} }
</SCRIPT>
```

And the code for when the slideshow is called:

```
<A HREF="JavaScript:slide()"><IMG SRC="/a.jpeg" NAME="img"></a>
```

Thanks!
- Patrick

Comment: That code doesn't appear to preload anything.

Comment: Just a note: You don't need the `language="javascript` bit as it has been superseded by type="text/javascript" which even then is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images start to load once they have a `src` attribute set, unless (unofficially) the element's css `display` property is set to `none`.

So, as long as you don't set the source of the `img` element or JS `Image` object, as appears to be the case in the code you posted, the image will not start loading.

Answer (score 0):

Using you images array,

```
var imgs = ["/a.jpeg","/b.jpeg","/c.jpeg","/d.jpeg","/e.jpeg"]
```

You can do this:

```
function preloadImages(){
    for(var i=0 ; i<imgs.lenght ; i++) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = "img/" + imglist[i];
    }
}
```

This function will **preload** all those images, so when you do the `slide()` the images are in browser cache.

This method doesn't work in all browsers, so when I need to do this trick, I also use a `div` with the size of 1x1 pixel (positioned outside the view) with all the images, like this:

```
<div>
    <img src="/a.jpeg" />
    <img src="/b.jpeg" />
    ...
</div>
```

This will also load all the images as soon as possible...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, thank you all for your responses. They've led me to my answer, which is just that I made a very silly mistake. I misunderstood the results from my website's analytics test, which seemed to indicate that all images were being downloaded into the cache. This was just a goofball misreading of the results that led me on a wild goose chase, which was sustained by my lack of JavaScript understanding. I realized it after going back to the test to respond here. It all behaves as I intended with a minor adjustment. Thank you!